# Blowfish encryption on C# and PHP yields different results

Tags: c#, php, encryption, blowfish

I'm trying to do a Blowfish encryption, but results in decryption an C#-encrypted code are not the same.
I used this library in C#:
https://defuse.ca/source/blowfish.cs
and this self-written code to encrypt:

```
$td = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($td, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

echo "Original data: $data<br />"; 

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt($td, $blowfish_key, $dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo "Encrypted data: " . bin2hex($encrypted_data)  . "<br />";
$x ="1e9a532f6391071e04ac46dfd4ffa1e324665ef7f1e75b8c2ea6ebabd75fd04d8"; //result from C#
$data = mcrypt_decrypt($td, $blowfish_key, $x /*$encrypted_data*/, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo trim($data);
```

Could anybody help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.
CH

Comment: I'm no crypto expert, but aren't you going to get different results by using a different `iv` between your C# and PHP code?

Comment: Hmm... You've got right! But I'm not sure how to set it declared, and is it safe.. This should be 8-chars string or what?

Comment: IIRC the `iv` can [and must] be sent/stored with the encrypted data as it is essentially a nonce, and must be used in the decryption process. It is the `$blowfish_key` that you want to cloak in secrecy. No idea how long the `iv` supposed to be, though. That's why `mcrypt_get_iv_size()` exists.

Comment: Uh.. you're declaring a random `iv` in PHP and then trying to decrypt the data you've encryted in C# with a totally different `iv`? If you're familiar with hashing passwords for storage think of the `iv` as being roughly equivalent to a salt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are 2 problems in your PHP code:

first:
mcrypt expects binary data ... no strings with hex encoded bytes ... (hex2bin() or pack() will convert that for you)

second: the IV ... your blowfish.cs generates a random IV for you, and puts that (8 bytes) in front of the cyphertext ... while your php codes generates a new random IV which will not work for decryption

suggestion:

c#

```
var fish = new BlowFish("0000000000000000");
var cs_output=fish.Encrypt_CBC("This is a test of the blowfish.cs file");
```

php

```
$cs_output="27c7c634ead1d28bfe64821a28ef909311e1f655150f24eec27abff1376a7a8712e7962fdbb0150bfc0882078cb99e67";

$iv=pack("H*" , substr($cs_output,0,16));
$blowfish_key=pack("H*" , "0000000000000000"); // key in this example is all zero
$x =pack("H*" , substr($cs_output,16)); 
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $blowfish_key, $x , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Comment: I don't understand it... Could you explain it more? http://pastebin.com/qffNQD88 doesn't work

Comment: in your pastebin code you are calling the c# blowfish class with a non-hex-key "KD921231X3123211" ... that parameter is meant to be a hexadecimal number ... your value only works because the GetHex() function in blowfish.cs is broken ... on the php side, you will get a different result, and therefore a different key ...